# ViewPager2 при установки offscreenPageLimit неверно отрисовываются элементы

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-viewpager

Есть `ViewPager2` в котором отображаются карточки. В качестве адаптера используется `RecyclerView.Adapter`. В адаптер поступает список моделей, в которых содержатся коды цветов для градиента фона карточек. Для `ViewPager2` установлен `offscreenPageLimit`, чтобы были видны соседние карточки. Проблема заключается в том, что первые offscreenPageLimit + 1 карточкам устанавливается одинаковый цвет, хотя во `ViewHolder` приходят разные модели с разными цветами. Аналогичная ситуация при использовании `RecyclerView` вместо `ViewPager2`.
[Демонстрация проблемы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acSoq.jpg).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val adapter: Adapter by lazy { Adapter() }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.pager)

        val pageMarginPx = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.dim8).toInt()
        pager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
        pager.setPageTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(pageMarginPx))
        pager.adapter = adapter

        val items = listOf(
            Model("CARD 1","#000000", "#FFFFFF"),
            Model("CARD 2","#FFF0EB", "#FFC1AF"),
            Model("CARD 3","#BF559B", "#DE7ECB"),
            Model("CARD 4","#FFEEC2", "#F8C33D")
        )

        adapter.setItems(items)
    }

    class Adapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

        private var items: List<Model> = emptyList()

        fun setItems(items: List<Model>) {
            this.items = items
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.bind(items[position])
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

        class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
            fun bind(item: Model) {
                Log.d("TAG", "$item")
                val background =
                    itemView.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient) as GradientDrawable

                val colorList = intArrayOf(Color.parseColor(item.start), Color.parseColor(item.end))

                background.colors = colorList
                binding.container.background = background

                binding.txt.text = item.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте так ` (background.mutate() as GradientDrawable).colors  = colorList`

Comment: @IR42 это действительно помогло, спасибо. Напишите, пожалуйста, подробнее в чем заключалась проблема, и я приму Ваш ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawable могут использовать общий, так называемый ConstantState для переиспользования различных данных. Поэтому изменение одного drawable может затронуть сразу несколько.
[image: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9l0GmPwgCzk/Sf0SgfbQcVI/AAAAAAAAAD8/xKcxTQCAxn0/s400/shared_states.png]

Чтобы всё такие отвязаться от этого общего состояния, то нужно вызвать метод `mutate()` и дальше уже менять drawable.
После вызова `mutate()`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
(background.mutate() as GradientDrawable).colors = colorList
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!